# Syntax error (Missing operator) in excel vba

Tags: excel, syntax-error, vba

I am getting the error 'Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression:

```
'tblFICL.Product = Muni/Money Market AND tblFICL.Broker_Code = WELLS'
```

The full vba query is below. I am guessing this has something to do with my variables `prdct` and `bkr`.  What syntax am I missing in this query?

```
'Set and Excecute SQL Command'
strSQL = "SELECT tblFICL.Email " _
    & " FROM tblFICL " _
    & " WHERE tblFICL.Product = " & prdct & " AND tblFICL.Broker_Code = " & bkr & ""
```

Been looking at this all day, any help would be greatly appriciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may need apostrophes before and after your values. Try code below

```
strSQL = "SELECT tblFICL.Email " _
    & " FROM tblFICL " _
    & " WHERE tblFICL.Product = '" & prdct & "' AND tblFICL.Broker_Code = '" & bkr & "'"
```

Comment: This works!  Thank you!  Now I will be able to sleep tonight.

Comment: @loha86 -- you can also say thank-you by accepting the answer. Click the checkmark at the top left.